# How to truncate an expression bit width in Verilog in 2023?

Tags: system-verilog

I have the same question as here:
[How to truncate an expression bit width in Verilog?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67281/how-to-truncate-an-expression-bit-width-in-verilog)

**But** I was hoping that in 2023, there would be more interesting answers that in 2013!

My specific use-case:

`localparam logic [31:0] BAR0_OFFSET_MASK = {32{1'b1}} << (10);`

Some tools complains that LHS is 32 whereas RHS is 42, and I would like to select part of the result of the shift operation without creating a temporary variable or a function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools that complain that the RHS of the assignment width is 42 bits are incorrect. The width of a shift operation is determined by the width of its left operand.

Regardless, SystemVerilog added a select in a concatenation

```
localparam logic [31:0] BAR0_OFFSET_MASK =  { {32{1'b1}} << (10) }[31:0];
```

You could also use casts

```
localparam logic [31:0] BAR0_OFFSET_MASK =  32'( 32'('1) << (10)) ;
```

Comment: Many thanks for the very fast answer! I won't name the tool that begins with Spy and finish with drink... 
Great to see that the language advanced.